# Not able to save from Word to WebDAV folder (LOCK on files)

Tags: apache, ms-word, locking, webdav

I setup WebDAV on Ubuntu using `apache2` and the mods `dav`, `dav_fs` and `dav_lock`.

Connecting to WebDAV folders works fine, from both Windows and Linux clients. Even creating (writing) and modifying documents is possible.

Then only problem is when I try to save documents from Word. Word first creates the file on the server, but then following error appears:

**There has been a network or file permission error. The network connection may be lost**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291156/you-receive-a-there-has-been-a-network-or-file-permission-error--the-n (Solutions there don't help)

Apache `error.log`:

```
Could not DELETE /pinakos/admin/66AEE86C.tmp due to a failed precondition (e.g. locks).  [423, #0]
This resource is locked and an "If:" header was not supplied to allow access to the resource.  [423, #0]
Could not MOVE /pinakos/admin/6A71E678.tmp due to a failed precondition on the source (e.g. locks).  [424, #0]
An error occurred on another resource, preventing the requested operation on this resource.  [424, #0]
Could not DELETE /pinakos/admin/6A71E678.tmp due to a failed precondition (e.g. locks).  [423, #0]
This resource is locked and an "If:" header was not supplied to allow access to the resource.  [423, #0]
```

Virtual host (excerpt):

```
Alias /pinakos/admin /var/www/webdav/pinakos/admin
<Directory /var/www/webdav/pinakos/admin>
   DAV On
   AuthType Digest
   AuthName "webdav"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
<Location /pinakos/admin>
   Require user admin
</Location>
```

`www-data` has rw permissions for `/var/www` as well for the `DavLock` file.